# Is using proxies to circumvent rate limit to scrape data legal in India?

Tags: criminal-law, software, india, public-domain, hacking

I'm in India, and this is what the Indian Information Act of 2000/66F says on the matter:

> Indian Information Act 2000/66F
>
> Punishment for cyber terrorism.– Whoever,– with intent to threaten the unity, integrity, security or sovereignty of India or to strike terror in the people or any section of the people by–
>
> (i) denying or cause the denial of access to any person authorised to access computer resource; or
>
> (ii) attempting to penetrate or access a computer resource without authorisation or exceeding authorised access; or
>
> (iii) introducing or causing to introduce any computer contaminant,

Since the administrator of the API has authorised only a certain number of API calls for a network, can it be construed as a violation of 66F clause 2 if we try to circumvent the rate limit even though the information is on public domain?

Comment: Are your contemplated actions intended to threaten the unity, integrity, security or sovereignty of India or to strike terror in the people ?  That is what the law is trying to prohibit.

Comment: No, but the law is used as a precedent to ensure application security against DDoS attacks. My intention is to simply collect data available in the public domain. Can using proxies against rate limiters be argued as an action of DDoS?